# Whats wrong? Message: Undefined property

Tags: php

This is the error:

> *Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Products::$product_model Filename: controllers/Products.php Line
>   Number: 29*

This is my Controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Products extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session_data()):
            redirect(base_url());
        endif;
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $this->load->model('Admin_model');
        $this->load->model('product_model','products');
    }

    function session_data()
    {
        return $this->session->userdata('ADMIN_SESSION');
    }


  function show($page,$data = array(),$str = '')
    {
        $userdata = $this->session_data();
        $data['setting'] = $str;
        $data['admin'] = $this->Admin_model->get_id($userdata['empcom_id']);
        $data['cat'] = $this->product_model->get_cat(); 
        $this->load->view($page,$data);
    }
    function index()
    {


        $this->show('template/header');
        $this->show('admin/admin_menus');

        $this->show('product_view');
          $this->show('template/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading method:

```
$this->load->model('model_name', 'foobar');
$this->foobar->method();
```

refernce : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model

in your method you have assigned a different name for your product_model

```
$this->load->model('product_model','products');
```

> $data['cat'] = $this->product_model->get_cat();

change that to

> $data['cat'] = $this->products->get_cat();

Comment: Thank you Arun pandian M, you are correct! great thanks... its working now